# shade plugin not executing

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I need to get an uber jar for my Maven project. I am using shade plugin for the same. But on maven build (clean install) the shade plugin is not executed. My pom.xaml file includes this for shade plugin.

```
  <build>
  <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                      <mainClass></mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                  </transformers>

                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
      </build>
```

Solution: finally found the solution here [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208526/maven-shade-plugin-is-not-called-automatically-for-goal-package) which was to remove `<pluginManagement> </pluginManagement>`

Comment: First try to build on command line...furthermore show how you called Maven etc. your full pom file and what is missing?

Comment: I did a maven build on eclipse (goals: clean install) to get the jar file

Comment: As I mentioned on plain command line ....

Comment: Move the configuration from pluginManagement out of it...