# Maven running .JAR file claims missing dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I have a **Maven project** which uses a few external dependencies, mainly **Jackson**.
When I run `mvn clean -e install`, it creates a jar file as specified in the `target` directory. However, when I run this jar file with java in command line I get the error message:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.test.package.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException
```

The specific element of Jackson which it's getting confused over does not matter, the error message will point out whatever portion of Jackson the code uses first. The strange part is when I run the project from within IntelliJ, it works fine. It seems that the JAR file does not have access to the proper dependencies.

This is the relevant portion of the `pom.xml`:

```
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.test.package.Main</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0</version>
          <inherited>true</inherited>
          <configuration>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
            <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Is there something I should be doing for the built JAR file to run properly anywhere?

Comment: In Eclipse you have an option to package all required jar files into a single output jar file. Right click on project -> Export...  -> Runnable jar file

Comment: The other option is to copy the external dependencies to the folder with your jar or a valid classpath.

Comment: How do you run the JAR? Please add the complete command line you use to your question. And, off-topic, please consider changing the background (colors) of your web site. 1. black on magenta is hard to read and 2. I'm suffering from beginning eye cancer now. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Solved:
This solution from another thread fixed my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42231035/8402030
I had to add a plugin called Maven Shade which creates an uber jar containing all dependencies. Additionally had to remove the plugin from the  tag.
Not entirely sure why it matters that the plugin is outside of . If anyone knows, feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: The `pluginManagement` tag defines the configurations of plugins *if they are used* but doesn't actually configure them to be used. It provides one place for default configuration in a multi-module project.

Comment: @tgdavies Not only "in a multi-module project". Think of declaring the usage of the same plugin more than once in one and the same POM. Otherwise you're correct.